# JavaScript button that generates objects in order

Tags: javascript, html

i created a button in JS that generates GIFs randomly,
i would like to change that by making them appear in order and then repeat.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 {
 image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/P6lX0T2MzYpdC/giphy.gif',
 },
 {
 image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/uWdVKl2xN1eVi/giphy.gif',
 },
  {
 image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',
 }
    ];
  
    
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * factsArr.length);
      document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[idx].image)
    })
      
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<img id="image"></img>
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? current behavior? expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet below, I used a global `currImage` variable which increases on each click and resets when reaching the image array size. The image is taken from the array's `currImage` index.

```js
 
// Init the variable 
var currImage = 0;

window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/P6lX0T2MzYpdC/giphy.gif'},
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/uWdVKl2xN1eVi/giphy.gif'},
        { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif'}
    ];
    
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
        document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);

        // increment the variable on each click
        currImage++;

        //reset the variable when it reaches the image array size
        if (currImage == factsArr.length)
           currImage = 0;
    })
      
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<img id="image"></img>
```

Comment: @TalalKhraisat Happy to help. If this answer helped, accepting it as correct would be appreciated.

Comment: This can also be done using modular arithmetic. `currImage++; currImage %= factsArr.length` The benefit here is that you can combine the two statements and do `factsArr[(currImage++) % factsArr.length].image`.
But using an if statement makes it more clear what's going on anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a numeric variable to indicate the current index of the array to use.

```js
const factsArr = [
  {image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/P6lX0T2MzYpdC/giphy.gif'},
  {image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/uWdVKl2xN1eVi/giphy.gif'},
  {image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif'}
];
const tot = factsArr.length;
let c = 0;

document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('image').src = factsArr[c++ % tot].image;
});
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button><br>
<img id="image">
```